# Point subdomain to port on server

Tags: dns, subdomain

I'd like to point a subdomain to an IP address plus a port number, but I have no idea how to do so, and Google isn't being very helpful. Any suggestions?

Comment: DNS won't do this for you. For a web site requirement I set up a skeleton page with just a redirect to the right socket. You might be able to get mod_rewrite to do it if you're using Apache. A little more detail on your requirement might help

Comment: I have a server for a non-standard protocol being hosted on a rather undesirable port, and I'd like to be able to redirect- oh, I see. So, there isn't really a way to point an undesirable port to a desirable one?

Comment: If you're running a system with proper routing software, yes, you can do that. Here I'm talking Linux with `iptables`. (here's a [possible solution](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/iptables-redirect-from-one-local-port-to-another-865276/)) I don't know about Windows. In either case you're outside the remit of Stack Overflow. Try posting on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across this question while looking through my posting history, so I figured I may as well answer it now that I have more knowledge of the subject. What I was looking for were [SRV records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record), which can be used to point a subdomain to a service on a port. However, the service must explicitly provide SRV support in order for this to work properly.

If the service will only be accessed through a web browser, it may be more practical to add a VirutalHost containing a reverse proxy to Apache. This is useful for services such as CI servers or Tomcat instances.